# Get Resharper Formatting to Match Visual Studio Formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, code-formatting

I have a legacy system that uses the following settings for indentation for all languages in Visual Studio.

Tab Size: 8
Indent Size: 4
Keep Tabs

When I let Visual Studio format my code, I get the following:

[image]

When I let Resharper format the code. I get the following:

[image]

I've searched Google, Stack Overflow and have played with tons of options in both Visual Studioand Resharper. I still can't get Resharper formatting to match. Can anyone help? I'd really like to use Resharper formatting/cleanup, but need to figure this out first.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper doesn't understand when indent size is different from the tab size, because this kind of formatting style has too few benefits, too many drawback and is rarely used. I suggest reformatting everything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was afraid that this might be the case. I'll wait to see if anyone else has and answer, but I don't have high hopes. Now I get to decide if the benefits of reformatting everything out-weights the negatives of messing with source control history for every file in this HUGE project.

Comment: @PaulFox Seeing as how Dmitry works on ReSharper, I wouldn't wait too long.   If you do reformat, note that some source control solutions can skip witespace for you (like `git blame -w`, or `diffmerge /ignorespace`).  But it is a pain either way.